# Resetting URLSession.shared credentials

Tags: swift

I'm trying to do some api requests (with credentials) using URLSession.shared however it's not behaving as expected.

When the user first enters their credentials I set them as the default for the session using the following.

```
let credential = URLCredential(user: username, password: password, persistence: .forSession)
URLCredentialStorage.shared.setDefaultCredential(credential, for: myProtectionSpace)
```

I would then fire off the first url request using this.  For this example lets say the request is trying to access https://myapi.com/go.

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    // do stuff
}.resume()
```

This works great, the credentials get passed along and everything, until I need the user to sign off.  When I store different credentials, even with a bad password, the request to https://myapi.com/go will still come back OK and a 401 challenge doesn't appear to get issued.

I've tried all the following things and nothing seems to purge the session's credentials for that specific URL.

```
// Attempt #1: doesn't work
URLSession.shared.reset {
     // I confirmed this eliminates all credentials in the URLCredentialStorage.shared
     // store updated credentials and fire off new request here
}

// Attempt #2: doesn't work
URLCredentialStorage.shared.remove(credential, for: myProtectionSpace)
URLSession.shared.invalidateAndCancel()
// store updated credentials and fire off new request here 

// Attempt #3: doesn't work
URLCredentialStorage.shared.remove(credential, for: myProtectionSpace)
URLSession.shared.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
// store updated credentials and fire off new request here
```

The server doesn't seem to issue a 401 challenge after the first successful request to https://myapi.com/go therefore the revised credentials aren't getting used.  Am I forced to use a custom URLSession just because of this?

Comment: have you tried `URLCredentialStorage.shared.set(credential, for: myProtectionSpace)` instead of the setDefault one?

Comment: I tried that too, same result

Comment: I've found I've had to call [`URLSession.reset()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1411479-reset) to get it to 'reset' the the session, and therefore the credentials.